# Roles.GetRolesForUser() returns empty array

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-roles

I'm using `Roles.GetRolesForUser()` and when I call it I get `{string[0]}`.  However, when I type in a users name as a hard coded string like this: `Roles.GetRolesForUser("theloggedinusersname")`, I get `{string[2]} [0]: "AccountingAdmin" [1]: "Admin"`.  For the record, I also get values for `Roles.IsUserInRole` and `User.Identity`.

Here is how I have my Web.config set up:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
             applicationName="[MyAppName]" 
             name="DefaultRoleProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[MyPublicKeyToken]" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Clue:  "theloggedinusersname" is **not equal** to `User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: what is the result of `Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name)`?

Comment: try looking at http://peterkellner.net/2006/10/20/loginfailswithiisnotcasini/

Comment: The result of `Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name)` is `{string[0]}`

Comment: seems "theloggedinusersname" not equal to  `User.Identity.Name` am i right?

Comment: Is User.Identity.Name equal to 'theloggedinusersname' (log in user)? I am asking this because GetRolesForUser call GetRolesForUser with HttpContext.User as a parameter.

Comment: Damith and Koste, you are correct, "theloggedinusersname" is not equal to User.Identity.Name.

Comment: So, these two values are not equal.  What does this mean?  Am I pulling the wrong value from my database somehow?

Comment: Are you using a Membership provider? Where are you getting "theloggedinusersname" from?

Comment: GWB, by "theloggedinusersname" I mean to say that if I type in the logged in user's name as a hard coded string into the Roles.GetRolesForUser() as a param then I get the appropriate roles returned for that user.

Comment: @AaronSalazar OK, so how are you identifying the currently-logged-in user? Membership provider? Custom implementation?